# Incorrect Url.Action /routes behaviour? Asp.net mvc 4

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-routing

found interested case with routes in asp.net mvc.

Let's create clear empty solution with asp.net mvc 4 project.

Routes :

```
//more detail route
routes.MapRoute(
            name: "{lang}/category/{category}",
            url: "{lang}/category/{category}",                
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index" }
        );
        //more general route
        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "{lang}",
            url: "{lang}",

            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index"  }
        );
```

in HomeController :

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Index(string category = null)
{


   return View("~/Views/Home/index.cshtml");
}
```

Can anyone say **WHY it returns "/en" for all Url.Action calls at urls except "/en/category/1"? 
I mean, if i go to, on example, /samplePage/blabla - it works as expected (generated url in html : /en), but when i go to "/en/category/1" - generated url in html changing to "en/category/1"!**

```
  Url.Action("Index","Home", new {lang="en"}); //different behaviour for "/en" and  "/en/category/1" urls
```

Does current routeData from url should affect Url generate function?

**UPDATE**
Same problem discussed here : [UrlHelper.Action includes undesired additional parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20349681/urlhelper-action-includes-undesired-additional-parameters) . Provided by @AndyNichols

Comment: See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20349681/urlhelper-action-includes-undesired-additional-parameters) where they had a similar problem. It seems that the existing route values are kept unless overwritten.

Comment: @Andy Nichols Maybe you should make this an answer so he can mark this question answered.